# Issue merging gulp streams to same destination

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, gulp

Trying to merge multiple streams to the same destination using `merge2`, but when I compare the results of the working, pre-merge2 work and the implementation below, I'm missing complete files from the concatenated resultant file.

Note: I can't run babel on all the files because it also runs on TPL that are being used which also causes fatal errors in the app.

Before I process these changes, I take in all of the files that need to be processed for the task and then I splice out the files that need to be treated differently:

```
let widgets = [];
fileNames.forEach(function (item, index, array) {
    if (/widgets\/special.+\/special.+\.js/ig.test(item)) {
        widgets.push(array.splice(index, 1)[0]);
    }
});
```

and then I merge the streams:

```
return plugins.merge2([
    gulp.src(widgets).pipe(plugins.babel({presets: ['es2015']})),
    gulp.src(fileNames)
]).pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(plugins.concat(targetName))
    .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write('../sourcemap'))
    .pipe(plugins.chmod(777))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(destPath))
    .on('end', cb);
```

I suspected that babel might be causing the issue so I modified my code:

```
return plugins.merge2([
    gulp.src(widgets),
    gulp.src(fileNames)
]).pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(plugins.concat(targetName))
    .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write('../sourcemap'))
    .pipe(plugins.chmod(777))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(destPath))
    .on('end', cb);
```

Yet, the issue persists and it seems like only *some* of the files in the widgets array are being concatenated to the same file. Is my approach wrong? Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Try using [`merge-stream`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-stream) instead of `merge2`. If the issue persist you'll have to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Already tried it using merge-stream, which creates even more issues. Due to the nature of this question it's difficult to provide a MCV, but I'll see what I can dig up.